# package installed in anaconda\lib\site-packages and found in spyder, but not in a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, jupyter

I have installed the azureml package and can see it in . . .anaconda\lib\site-packages:

[image]

If I run `import azureml.dataprep as dprep` in a python script in Spyder (launched from Anaconda Navigator), it works.  But, if I open one of my anaconda environments with jupyter notebook and try running the same line of code, I get an error about module not found for azureml:

[image]

I thought perhaps the problem was that the package needed to be installed for that specific environment, but azureml is not available as a package for install via the anaconda environments > install packages interface (there is an azure package but not an azureml package).

So, I followed instructions to use conda prompt to install a package into a specific environment.  Instructions I followed:
[image]

(those are from [this link](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment))

And here is the result of following the instructions (it looked like it installed the package into the env):
[image]

But, I got the exact same error when trying to import the package in the environment started as a jupyter notebook.  Then, I closed anaconda navigator completely just in case, but that also didn't change the result.

Any ideas about what I'm either doing wrong or how I can manually install this package into a specific anaconda environment?

Answer (score 1):

You did the right thing to install the package into the environment. Btw, `pip` is automatically installed by `conda` into any environment that has Python, so installing it shouldn't have been necessary.

Are you sure that the environment that you installed into is the one in which your notebook kernel is running? Start the notebook and execute

```
!conda env list
```

That will give you a list of environments, and an asterisk `*` next to the one that is active.

You can also call `pip` directly from a notebook cell:

```
!pip install azureml
```

That will install into the conda environment in which the kernel is running.

Comment: Thank you!  In the notebook itself, doing !pip install azureml just resulted in it showing that the requirement was already met.  However, doing !pip install azureml.dataprep worked!